# Calculating WGS84 coordinates on a circle given center coordinates, radius, speed and elapsed time

Tags: geolocation, geospatial

I want to calculate the position of an airplane going a constant speed after a specific time when going around a circle at a certain radius. The circle should not be affected by the latitude.
The starting position does not matter, as long as it is consistent, same for accuracy.

My maths and geodesy skills are not great so any pointer would help.

Currently I'm calculating:
`Lat = centerLat + radius * sin(distanceInRad) Long = centerLong + radius * cos(dostanceInRad)`

This seems to work somewhat, but it is not a good circle and I'm also not sure if it's the correct way to calculate.